# What dragged the Collector's servant towards the Infinity Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

During the [*Guardians of the Galaxy*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/)'s visit at the *Collector*'s he opens the mysterious orb and reveals the true nature of its content, being one of the *Infinity Stones*. But then suddenly his servant approaches the stone as in trance and touches it (ultimately destroying herself and the *Collector*'s den in the wake of this), uttering something like:

> I'll not be your slave anymore!

I wonder though, **what dragged her that strongly towards the *Infinity Stone*?** Was she simply hungry for its supposed power, being suppressed all the time (it's established earlier that the *Collector* isn't particularly nice to his servants) or is there anything more to this, like some kind of unnatural attraction emerging from the *Infinity Stone* itself (similar to the *One Ring* maybe)?

Comment: No dragging occurred. She decided to do it.

Comment: @OrangeDog Well, yeah, not literal "dragging".

Comment: Not figurative either.

Comment: @OrangeDog Maybe not if you employ a narrow interpretation of "dragging" that excludes her very own motivation. It's a really general word. If the purpose of your comment was to say that there wasn't any *external* force that drew her to it, upvoting the 6 year old answer that says that would probably have the same effect. ;-)

Comment: Urgh, I never check the dates on these things.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having seen the movie several times, I don't think anything was "dragging" the girl (Carina, possibly?) towards the Infinity Stone other than her own desire. She had just finished listening to Tanleer explain how powerful the stone is, and earlier in the movie we had seen how he verbally abuses her and forces her to do very menial and back-breaking work.

She saw the stone as a possibility to escape. What you're interpreting as her being pulled toward the stone, I think, is actually her being very *hesitant* to touch it. Her own internal conflict between the need to escape her situation vs. her fear of the stone is what makes her take so long to try and grab it, but obviously, her desire to be free wins out.